# execute code in script element after external js file loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

That's gonna be an abstract question so no code example involved here. Hope you and I saty on the same page till the end of this post ^^"

In my index.html I have  element defined async and defer both true.
Additionally, And right after that script element (DOM wise), I have  element where I call function exists in the external js file.

unfortunately error undefined thrown over the function. I geuss because the js file ain't fully downloaded while the function in the second script executed.

tnx for all answears. stackoverflow do you magic...

Comment: Have a look at _script loaders_ such as [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) or [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/)

Comment: tnx ! problem solved! In loaders we trust ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move your second script in the callback of your first script ? so when the first one loads and succeeds, the second one is executed.

And it will be helpful if you share your code, it depends on what the scripts actually do.

Comment: The second script dynamically written from  the server.
Im developing compiler.
As I already said,  this is a conceptual question not a practical one.
The specific case does not matter....

tnx for u're answear anyway :)